# how to add JS listener effectively

Tags: javascript, listener

I'm working on a class assignment to create a todo list.  In my CustomPrompt() function I create a listener to capture the enter key.  So it seems that each time I add a todo I'm creating a new listener.  Is that correct and is there a way to do this with just one listener?

```js
function CustomPrompt(){
 this.render = function(dialog,func){
  var winW = window.innerWidth;
   var winH = window.innerHeight;
  var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
   var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');

  dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
   dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
  dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
   dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
   dialogbox.style.display = "block";

  document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = '&nbsp';
   document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
  document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML += '<br><input id="prompt_value1"  >';
  document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '&nbsp';
  document.getElementById('prompt_value1').focus();
  //document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Prompt.ok(\''+func+'\')">OK</button> <button onclick="Prompt.cancel()">Cancel</button>';
  const node = document.getElementById("prompt_value1");
  node.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {

     Prompt.ok('newToDo');

          
      }
    });
 }
 this.cancel = function(){
  document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
 }
 this.ok = function(func){
  var prompt_value1 = document.getElementById('prompt_value1').value;
  window[func](prompt_value1);
  document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
 }
}
var Prompt = new CustomPrompt();

function newToDo(val){
   
   var ul = document.getElementById('todo-list'); //ul
   var li = document.createElement('li');//li

   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.value = 1;
      checkbox.name = "todo[]";

    li.appendChild(checkbox);

    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var att = document.createAttribute("class");
        att.value = 'centerSpan';
        span.setAttributeNode(att);

    var text = document.createTextNode(val);
    span.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(span);

    var but = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        but.classList.add("rightButton");
        text = document.createTextNode('X');
        but.append(text);



    li.appendChild(but);
    console.log(li);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}



window.onload= function(){

const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')





var ulist = document.getElementById('todo-list');

ulist.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
  // List item found!  Output the ID!
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
 }
});

}
```

```css
#dialogoverlay{
 display: none;
 opacity: .8;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 background: #0388c6;
 border-radius:15px;
 width:550px;
 z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#0388c6; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #0388c6; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#ccc; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background: #00547d; padding:20px; color:#FFF;border-radius: 30px;}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #0388c6; padding:10px; text-align:right; }







html, body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flow-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title, .controls, .button {
  flex: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.todo-delete {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.todo-container:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
  display:inline-block;
  width:5%;
  margin:0;
  margin-left:20%;
}

.centerSpan{
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     
     <title>TODO App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>

     <div id="dialogbox">
       <div>
          <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
          <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
          <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="container center">
       <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
       <div class="flow-right controls">
         <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
         <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
       </div>

       <button class="button center"  onclick="Prompt.render('Input a new ToDo:','newToDo')">New ToDo</button>

       <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
     </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called *Event Delegation*. You set a single listener on the parent element of all the ToDos. Then use the event object to determine the target element. I'm sure you've seen code like this:

```
element.addEventListener('click', newTodo);
```

Then, inside newTodo(e) you would get the value the same way:

```
var prompt_value1 = document.getElementById('prompt_value1').value;
```

This idea takes advantage of one of the most import features of the language. The eventing system allows the event to *bubble* up to the parent. Investigate the event phases of JS.

Comment: thanks   My render function get's the name of the function to call.  How do I get that into the listener of the parent, which in this case is #dialogboxbody? I'm able to do it with a global variable but was wondering if there was a way not to use global

Comment: it appears the `newTodo()` function is already a global. So see my edit.

Comment: ahh, but the idea is to get the name of the function from the html.  This makes the js more generic

Comment: I'm sorry, my friend. You and I will diverge here then. There is nothing in modern practice that advocates the use of inline JavaScript placed inside HTML. Your use of window.onload() is also discouraged in every modern practice treatise one can find on the topic. There are some software engineering concepts that will allow you to keep your code modular and more generic, but that isn't one of them. So best of luck to you with your project.

Comment: if you would like a different take on how to do this, check this blog post: https://code-maven.com/todo-in-html-and-javascript by Gabor Szabo

Comment: we can get rid of the windows.onload with the defer attribute.  As far as inline JS in html we are only passing a variable with the onclick event.  <button class="button center"  onclick="Prompt.render('Input a new ToDo:','newToDo')">New ToDo</button>  This has been standard in JS for quite a while.  This allows us to have a generic customPrompt and any function we want to direct the prompt to.